# Show that if $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, then $A \times B$ is closed in $X \times Y$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof?

> Show that if $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, then $A \times B$ is closed in $X \times Y$.

Let $x \times y \in X \times Y - A \times B$. Then, either $x \notin A$ or $y \notin B$ (or both).

If $x \notin A$, consider the set $(X - A) \times Y$. Clearly, $x \times y \in (X-A) \times Y$. Since $X-A$ is open in $X$ and $Y$ is open in $Y$, $(X-A) \times Y$ is open in $X \times Y$, and clearly, $(X-A) \times Y \subseteq X \times Y - A \times B$.

On the other hand, if $x \in A$, it must be the case that $y \notin B$. By similar reasoning, the set $X \times (Y-B)$  is open in $X \times Y$, and $X \times (Y-B) \subseteq X \times Y - A \times B$.

Since every element of $X \times Y - A \times B$ is a part of an open set which is a subset of $X \times Y - A \times B$, it follows that $X \times Y - A \times B$ is open. Therefore, $A \times B$ is closed.

Comment: up to some typos  ... you want $y \not\in B$ not $x\not\in B$ (third line and sixth line)... fine

Comment: In short, $A\times B$ is closed because $\complement(A\times B)=(X\times\complement B)\cup (\complement A\times Y)$ is open, being the union of (two) open sets.

Comment: I want to say that $x\times y$ is the most horrible way to denote the ordered pair $(x,y)$ I have seen so far.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's the convention used in Munkres.

Comment: firstly the OP asked for verification of the proof in particular he wants to know if what he did was right.

furthermore, indeed, the notation $x\times y$ will lead to confusion in deeper topics of topology, when it means something different

Comment: @user154185: How unfortunate, then.

Answer (score 1):

your proof looks perfectly fine, just a few things to mention.

usually you write $(x,y)$ instead of $x\times y$ for an element in $X\times Y$.

I would omit the term "$Y$ is open in $Y$", since not all product of open sets are open. Here it is rather confusing and the correct argument is just that $(X-B)$ is open.

You don't have to do those two cases. By symmetry you can just say: assume wlog $x\not \in A$.

So this was just constructive critisism and I hope it helps you.